# mongoimport CSV with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, csv, pymongo

I found a command for mongodb which lets you import CSV files as a whole: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

like this:

```
mongoimport --db users --type csv --headerline --file /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

However, there seems to be no mention of this in Pymongo. Does it exists, and if so what is the syntax for it? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongoimport` is a command-line program that you install. Instructions for installing MongoDB, including its tools like `mongoimport`, are here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-community/

Once you've done that, execute `mongoimport` from the Unix shell or Windows command prompt, whichever system you're on.

PyMongo is a Python driver for MongoDB, it allows you to write Python code that executes queries and commands on MongoDB over the network. PyMongo is separate from the MongoDB tools like `mongoimport`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! In other words, I have to execute `mongoimport` from the terminal and I cannot call it from within PyMongo? I ran it now from the command line but I was interested if there is something in PyMongo to accomplish the same.

Comment: Right, you have to execute mongoimport from the terminal.

Comment: Thanks! That's all I wanted to know :)

Comment: @Niko you can always call `system("my_command_line_command")` in python