# How do I import json file using pymongo?

Tags: json, file, import, pymongo

I try using this but it won't work.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
client('mongoimport --db myDatabase --collection restaurants --file c:\restaurants\restaurants.json')
print ('json import sucessfully')
```

Greatly appreciate of any helps. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999171/mongoimport-csv-with-pymongo), `mongoimport` is a command-line program and not in the PyMongo API.

However you can use a different approach:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
with open('restaurants.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
client['myDatabase']['restaurants'].insert_many(data)
```

If your json file is too big, you can use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) lib to run the command-line program inside a python program. Check some SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450285/executing-command-line-programs-from-within-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)